# Not understanding reduce with anonymous function

Tags: clojure

I am reading Living Clojure, and this example of `reduce` is throwing me off.

```
(reduce (fn [r x]
          (+ r (* x x)))
        [1 2 3])
```

`[1 2 3]` is the input to `reduce`, along with the anonymous function.

If each member of the vector is passed in, that would only fill in `r` or `x` parameters, where does the other parameter come from?

Is there a way to step through to watch the parameters and output change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a [description of the first argument on ClojureDocs](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/reduce), but I have to admit it's not really descriptive.

The function you pass as the first argument takes two parameters, the first one is *total*, the second one is *current*. If you call `reduce` with only two arguments, *total* in first iteration is the first item of the collection, while *current* in first iteration is the second item of the collection. If you pass three parameters, the second one is *initial value* that is passed as *total* in the first iteration, while the first item of the collection is passed as *current* in first iteration:

```
(reduce (fn [r x] (+ r x)) 0 [1 2 3])
```

would iterate like this:

```
(+ 0 1) ;; initial value and first item of the collection
(+ (+ 0 1) 2) ;; result and second item of the collection
(+ (+ (+ 0 1) 2) 3) ;; result and third item of the collection
```

while without initial value

```
(reduce (fn [r x] (+ r x)) [1 2 3])
```

would iterate like this:

```
(+ 1 2) ;; no initial value -> first and second item of the collection
(+ (+ 1 2) 3) ;; result and third item of the collection
```

You could as well just add a `println` to see each iteration's inputs:

```
(reduce
  (fn [r x]
      (do
        (println (str "r = " r ", x = " x ", (* x x) = " (* x x) ", (+ r (* x x)) = " (+ r (* x x))))
        (+ r (* x x))))
  [1 2 3])
```

the result of running it in REPL is

```
r = 1, x = 2, (* x x) = 4, (+ r (* x x)) = 5
r = 5, x = 3, (* x x) = 9, (+ r (* x x)) = 14
14
```

Comment: There's also another answer that, in my opinion, could be very helpful to understand `reduce`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25026200/1287643